# PHP preg_replace Regex for ATOM Feed

Tags: php, regex, atom-feed

I'm trying to eliminate string patterns such as `&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/em&amp;gt;` from my ATOM feed using regex preg_replace in PHP to update a description field on a website.

I wrote an expression that works partially, however it is still not fully working and whenever I make changes to it such as adding a '/' before the expression, nothing gets returned for the description field.

My current code is as follows:

```
            $mycontent = substr(sanitizeContent($post['content']), 0, 200);
            $newcontent = sanitizeContent(preg_replace('(&.*?;)', '', $mycontent));

function sanitizeContent($content) {
    return strip_tags(preg_replace('/<iframe.*?\/iframe>/i','', $content));
}

            $posts[] = [
            'post_title' => $post['title'],
            'post_content' => sanitizeContent($newcontent)
];
```

Here is a preview of what is happening: https://regex101.com/r/Vlmt4V/3

This is the returned description string from the above code:

```
pemstrongWord count: 756  2.5 minutes/strong/em/p
pI’ve just returned from Hong Kong, where…
```

My intended result is:

```
I've just returned from Hong Kong, where...
```

What expression do I need to achieve this result? Thanks.

Comment: Hope I'm understanding what you're asking. Those are encoded html special characters. You could decode them, then use strip_tags: `$data = html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($input));
strip_tags($data);` This will give you back a string

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful :)

Comment: How about [`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) after parsing the file with a proper parser? Or is this file format somehow broken?

Comment: In addition to the above comments... using `.*`, with or without the `?` ungreedy modifier, will oftentimes cause you nothing but problems.  You *think* it will stop at the first semicolon, or whatever.  Often, it does not.

Comment: Thanks guys! @BrettGregson your suggestion worked for me.